# Custom Drop Down box in Ruby on Rails with links as a couple of the options

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So...basically, I want this in my drop down:

```
•Nothing
•Option 1
•Option 2
•Option 3
Link to another page
Link to another page
```

I tried throwing a link_to to a select tag... that didnt work...
any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there would be a way to do such a thing only using Rails as rails would only put your options under HTML `<option>` tags for the select box.

You would have to put an onchange attribute which points to a JavaScript function which would do your redirection using `window.location`.